# Error when building a project in VC++ 2010 Express

Tags: c++

I tried to see what is the problem(s) related to those error messages. I tried to check everything but still, I'm not finding the source of the error.

According to you, the obj error followed by error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol imp__is_CaptureVideo referenced in function, what is its provenance?

I'm using Visual Express C++ 2010.

Thank you.

```
1>IdsSimpleLiveDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__is_CaptureVideo referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CIdsSimpleLiveDlg::OnButtonStart(void)" (?OnButtonStart@CIdsSimpleLiveDlg@@AAEXXZ)
1>IdsSimpleLiveDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__is_StopLiveVideo referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CIdsSimpleLiveDlg::OnButtonStop(void)" (?OnButtonStop@CIdsSimpleLiveDlg@@AAEXXZ)
1>IdsSimpleLiveDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__is_SetImageMem referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CIdsSimpleLiveDlg::OnBnClickedButtonLoadParameter(void)" (?OnBnClickedButtonLoadParameter@CIdsSimpleLiveDlg@@AAEXXZ)
1>IdsSimpleLiveDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__is_AllocImageMem referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CIdsSimpleLiveDlg::OnBnClickedButtonLoadParameter(void)" (?OnBnClickedButtonLoadParameter@CIdsSimpleLiveDlg@@AAEXXZ)
1>IdsSimpleLiveDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__is_SetColorMode referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CIdsSimpleLiveDlg::OnBnClickedButtonLoadParameter(void)" (?OnBnClickedButtonLoadParameter@CIdsSimpleLiveDlg@@AAEXXZ)
1>IdsSimpleLiveDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__is_AOI referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CIdsSimpleLiveDlg::OnBnClickedButtonLoadParameter(void)" (?OnBnClickedButtonLoadParameter@CIdsSimpleLiveDlg@@AAEXXZ)
1>IdsSimpleLiveDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__is_FreeImageMem referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CIdsSimpleLiveDlg::OnBnClickedButtonLoadParameter(void)" (?OnBnClickedButtonLoadParameter@CIdsSimpleLiveDlg@@AAEXXZ)
1>IdsSimpleLiveDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__is_ParameterSet referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CIdsSimpleLiveDlg::OnBnClickedButtonLoadParameter(void)" (?OnBnClickedButtonLoadParameter@CIdsSimpleLiveDlg@@AAEXXZ)
1>IdsSimpleLiveDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__is_EnableMessage referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall CIdsSimpleLiveDlg::OpenCamera(void)" (?OpenCamera@CIdsSimpleLiveDlg@@AAE_NXZ)
1>IdsSimpleLiveDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__is_GetSensorInfo referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall CIdsSimpleLiveDlg::OpenCamera(void)" (?OpenCamera@CIdsSimpleLiveDlg@@AAE_NXZ)
1>IdsSimpleLiveDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__is_RenderBitmap referenced in function "private: long __thiscall CIdsSimpleLiveDlg::OnUEyeMessage(unsigned int,long)" (?OnUEyeMessage@CIdsSimpleLiveDlg@@AAEJIJ@Z)
1>IdsSimpleLiveDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__is_ExitCamera referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CIdsSimpleLiveDlg::ExitCamera(void)" (?ExitCamera@CIdsSimpleLiveDlg@@AAEXXZ)
1>IdsSimpleLiveDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__is_GetColorDepth referenced in function "private: int __thiscall CIdsSimpleLiveDlg::InitDisplayMode(void)" (?InitDisplayMode@CIdsSimpleLiveDlg@@AAEHXZ)
1>IdsSimpleLiveDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__is_SetDisplayMode referenced in function "private: int __thiscall CIdsSimpleLiveDlg::InitDisplayMode(void)" (?InitDisplayMode@CIdsSimpleLiveDlg@@AAEHXZ)
1>IdsSimpleLiveDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__is_GetDuration referenced in function "private: int __thiscall CIdsSimpleLiveDlg::InitCamera(unsigned long *,struct HWND__ *)" (?InitCamera@CIdsSimpleLiveDlg@@AAEHPAKPAUHWND__@@@Z)
1>IdsSimpleLiveDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__is_InitCamera referenced in function "private: int __thiscall CIdsSimpleLiveDlg::InitCamera(unsigned long *,struct HWND__ *)" (?InitCamera@CIdsSimpleLiveDlg@@AAEHPAKPAUHWND__@@@Z)
1>IdsSimpleLiveDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__is_ImageFormat referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CIdsSimpleLiveDlg::GetMaxImageSize(int *,int *)" (?GetMaxImageSize@CIdsSimpleLiveDlg@@AAEXPAH0@Z)
1>nafxcwd.lib(appcore.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___argv
1>nafxcwd.lib(appcore.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___argc
1>C:\Program Files\IDS\uEye\Develop\Source\SimpleLive\Debug\po.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 19 unresolved externals
```

Comment: Nice, but no one knows what are you actually trying. Seems like you did not link a library...

Comment: What is VB C++ 2010 btw? Mixing C++ and VB?

Comment: No sorry, it s Microsoft Visual C++ Express

Comment: When I have tried to include the suitable library, the errors keep showing up, the same ones!

Comment: As the errors state this is a link issue. The linker can not find what it is looking for. Can you give more information? code example, where you have the library installed, how are you adding it to your build settings... there is not enough information to solve this problem based on what you have provided.

Comment: I have added the correspondent library by clicking on the properties of my project and then, adding the directory to the Library Directories, as I said (VC++ rubric)

Comment: ...
IDSEXP   is_CaptureVideo           (HIDS hCam, INT Wait);

Comment: in one H file :
...
IDSEXP   is_CaptureVideo           (HIDS hCam, INT Wait);
...

in my Cpp file:
I m always using: is_CaptureVideo( m_hCam, IS_WAIT );


---

in the same CPP FILE :
is_StopLiveVideo( m_hCam, IS_WAIT );

in the same H file of above : 
IDSEXP   is_StopLiveVideo          (HIDS hCam, INT Wait);

PS: All the functions listed in the error box message of my first message are always inside an another one, like the following example:

void ExitCamera()
{
if( m_hCam != 0 )
{
is_EnableMessage( m_hCam, IS_FRAME, NULL );
...
is_ExitCamera( m_hCam );
m_hCam = NULL;
}

Comment: I dont understand your answer. Can you give me further details about what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

> I have added the correspondent library by clicking on the properties
>   of my project and then, adding the directory to the Library Directories

It seems like you've added the 'Additional Library Directory' to your VS Project - but didn't link the actual library file (windows extension: .lib). I think what you did is

`Project Properties -> Configuration Properties-> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories`

and added the directoy where your 3rd party '.lib' is inside. But in fact this doesn't link against that '.lib' file by itself (it just added the directory where VS is searching for the linked .lib files).

Try the following:
`Right click on your project -> Project Properties -> Configuration Properties-> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`

There is a list like:

```
'kernel32.lib;user32.lib;...;%(AdditionalDependencies)'
```

And somewehere inside there should the name of your '.lib file' appear. If it doesn't, you've to add it there. I.e. if the lib of your 3rd party library is named 'myLib.lib' you would insert there instead

```
'kernel32.lib;user32.lib;...;myLib.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)'
```